# Скрипт генерация случайных фраз

Tags: javascript

Генерация случайных слов, с задержкой по времени, где фраза "**НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО**" видна изначально, а после счетчика рондомно показывается одна фраза из переченя фраз, что в скрипте.

---

Требуется цифру-обратный счетчик, заключить в слова "Ждите (здесь обратный отсчет) секунд", пример:

```
НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО
Ждите 35 секунд
```

---

А также задать фразе "**Ждите 35 секунд**" со счетчиком, класс для CSS настроек.
Заранее благодарен.

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let easyTimer = (function(words, timer, element) {
      render = () => element.innerText = timer === 0 ? words[parseInt(Math.random() * words.length)] : timer
      let interval = setInterval(() => timer-- && 0 === timer ? render() && clearInterval(interval) : render(), 1000)
      render()
    })(
      ['ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'],
      35,
      document.querySelector('.rnd-word')
    )
  })
</script>
<div>
  <div>НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО</div>
  <div class="rnd-word"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  (function(words, timer, element) {
    render = () => {
      if (timer > 0)
        element.innerText = `Ждите ${timer} секунд`;
      else {
        element.innerText = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      timer--;
      render();
    }, 1000);
    render();
  })(
    ['ЯРКИЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'БЕСПЛАТНЫЕ КАРТИНКИ', 'КЛЕВЫЕ КАРТИНКИ'],
    3,
    document.querySelector('.rnd-word')
  );
});
```

```css
.rnd-word {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>НА САЙТЕ ТОЛЬКО</div>
  <div class="rnd-word"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @IgorЕсть проблемка. После того как исчезает  **"Ждите 35 секунд"**  и появляется рандомная фраза, ПРОДОЛЖАЕТ показываться весь перечень, рондомных фраз из скрипта.

Comment: @Budun Видимо, я вчера не понял, что нужно.

Comment: @IgorБлагодарю.Работает.